# Add button to other layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have activity and in that activity I want to add button to my layout.
This is code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

    ClassTabs tabs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        tabs = new ClassTabs(getApplicationContext());
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        tabs.addTab(button);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivity);


        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.actionbartest.ClassTabs
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

ClassTab:

```
public class ClassTabs extends LinearLayout{

    Button button = new Button(getContext());
    public ClassTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public ClassTabs(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
//  @Override
//  protected void onFinishInflate() {
//      super.onFinishInflate();
//      //((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabview, this);
//      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//        inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview, this);
//      
//  }

     private void init(Context context) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview, this);

        }
     public void addTab(Button child){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview, this);
            LinearLayout tab = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
            tab.addView(child);
     }

}
```

tab.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blue"
   >





</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I have activity where I have included other layout. I want to add button to this other layout(ClassTab) in code. I do something like method addTab(Button child) but I can't see that button when I start my application. How I can do that to add button in code my activity to included layout?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add the button or any other view dynamically, try the following:

```
//Create a button
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Test");

// Get the layout to add the button to
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);

// If necessary add some paramters
LayoutParams layout_params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// Finally add the button to the layout
layout.addView(myButton, layout_params);
```

In your code above, i don't see that you define caption text or layout parameters, so the button can just be invisible because of its missing content. Further more have a look at your layout, how it arranges its elements to be sure, that new elements get a visible position.